# Absolutely positioned element becoming invisible when it leaves container bounds

Tags: javascript, html, css

see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r0mwutr/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<p>How can i make div2 appear on screen?</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1
{
position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: yellow;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    z-index:1;
}

#div2
{
position:absolute;    
    background-color:green;
    left:30px;
    top:30px;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    z-index:2;
}

#div3
{
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:0px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:1;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var left = 0;
var div = document.getElementById("div2");
window.setInterval(function()
                   {
                  div.style.left = left + "px";
                       left = (left + 5) % 370;
                   }, 30);
```

**Problem:**
div2 becomes invisible when it leaves its parent's bounds. how can i fix this without changing parent of div2. also i cannot change width and height of the divs in my application.

Comment: You just need to alter your z-index on div1 to higher than the others.

Comment: sounds like the parent has an `overflow:hidden` on it? (from a brief skim). Make sure you aren't hiding overflow if you want to display outside of the parents bounding box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `z-index:1;` on div1 to `z-index:3;`
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jsbrown1/9r0mwutr/1/)

```
#div1
{
position:absolute;
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color: yellow;
left:0px;
top:0px;
z-index:3; // change this to a number higher than others
}
```