# Why is my absolutely positioned div invisible?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a slideout slideshow with three images and content mixings as if they were papers stashed in some folders, and there's a little handle at the bottom/top of each folder where it is named. Something on these lines:

[image]

Here's a sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s99mtvv5/

But, the absolutely positioned bookmarklet becomes invisible in the parts that lie outside the parent divs. I've tried altering the z-indexes as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234134/absolutely-positioned-element-becoming-invisible-when-it-leaves-container-bounds). But that doesn't help.

I've also tried negative margins, and `overflow` is not `hidden` in y direction. Could somebody help me in getting this right?

Edit: Some more descriptive text on what I am trying to achieve, if the image is not clear.

What I am trying to create is thus: Imagine that the slide-handle be an actual handle to a drawer. So, even when in open, or folded state (when I push them horizontally out of view as the user hovers on some other slide) the handles are always visible, so that I can pull the drawers back from them, if I wanted. Hence, they are not IN their containers, they jut outside it.

Comment: Have you had a look at jQuery accordion or even better, tabs?

Comment: Define "bookmarklet". Is it the yellow textbox?

Comment: @AndrewHoffman It is the one with class slide-handle

Comment: @Lee Tabs and Accordion have statically placed bookmarklets, I'm trying to create a slideshow. Right now, it doesn't have any javascript (as must be evident), but that will be put in place after I get the layout right.

Comment: @Anshul do you want the `TEXT1` box on your images??? Try - http://jsfiddle.net/s99mtvv5/1/

Comment: @MaryMelody Not quite, I am trying to push the TEXT1 out of the divs into clear space.

Answer (score 0):

```
.slide-handle {
    bottom: 25px;
}
.slide-frame {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s99mtvv5/4/

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: slide-handle IS positioned absolutely in my CSS. No, I am not looking for that. What I am trying to create is thus:
Imagine that the slide-handle be an actual handle to a drawer. So, even when in open, or folded state (when I push them horizontally out of view as the user hovers on some other slide) the handles are always visible, so that I can pull the drawers back from them, if I wanted. Hence, they are not IN their containers, they jut outside it.

Comment: @Anshul If I understand correctly, I believe you'll have to physically pull your slide-handles out of your absolutely positioned slide-frames. An absolutely positioned element is anchored relatively to the first relative or absolutely positioned parent. So if there is a parent above slide-frame that you want to anchor to, you'll need to pull it out.

Comment: Another way to say it is that, since .slide-handle is a direct descendant of .slide-frame, and .slide-frame is absolute, .slide-handle is anchored relative to .slide-frame. If .slide-frame weren't absolutely positioned, but #slideshow were positioned relative, then .slide-handle would anchor relative to #slideshow.

Comment: Yes, you are right that an absolutely positioned element is placed w.r.t. its absolutely/relatively placed parent. In our case, .slide-handle is the child of .slide-frame which is absolutely positioned. But, I CAN move the child element out of its parent if the child too is absolutely positioned. That is exactly what I want. To move it out of it's parent div, i.e. slide-frame, and not #slideshow. If you inspect the element in the source, you'll see that it is being positioned properly, but the text inside is not visible. I am asking why is THAT happening and how do I fix it.

Comment: Oh, well I see the text just fine. It says TEXT1, is semi-transparent, and inside the yellow box. Is that what the issue is, that you cannot see the text?

Comment: Oh, apparently there is more trouble. I have updated the fiddle by removing the <p> elements from slide-handle. http://jsfiddle.net/s99mtvv5/3/

You see, when none of the images is hovered on, the bookmarklet is not visible (but in inspect element, it will be in its appropriate place). On hover, a scroll-bar appears inside that element which then shows the TEXT1. However, this isn't what I am looking for. What I am trying to create is that the TEXT1 is always visible, like a hanging signboard, hovered or not.

Comment: No :( Chuck it. I'll find some other way of organizing it.